# "Could not find/open font" when using PHP gd

Tags: php, fonts, gd

I am getting this error `Could not find/open font` When trying `imagettftext()` in PHP.

The font file is there. What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer on bytes http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/4833-gd-could-not-find-open-font-font-problem

Setting the gdfontpath may help

```
$fontpath = realpath('.'); //replace . with a different directory if needed
putenv('GDFONTPATH='.$fontpath);
$font = 't.otf';
...
$box = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
```

Comment: Been fighting with this for far too long. OMG, thank you for this.